# Promises in Ember 1.0.0 - success callback not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ember.js, ember-data

This has been driving me mad. I've got a promise that calls a JSON endpoint to authenticate for a User. I'm able to see in the console that this call is now hitting the server and returning `200 OK` - for my sanity I also tailed the server log and it's also returning a `200` status, so I know the request is getting there.

However, when it comes to dealing with the response, my `fail()` callback is firing every time and updating the handlebars template, even when ostensibly (according to the server) the promise is succeeding. If I type in the wrong password, the server returns `401`, as I'd expect, so I know that the `200` is expected behaviour.

Here's the Ember Controller, that's dealing with a `save` action coming from a form.

```
Malinko.SessionsEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({ 
  actions: {    
    save: function() {
      var self = this;
      this.set('errorMessage', null);

      var data = {
        email: this.get('email'), 
        password: this.get('password'),
        api: 'true'
      };

      function done(response){
        console.log('Success, ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        self.transitionToRoute('index');
      };

      function fail(reason){
        console.log('Failed, ' + JSON.stringify(reason));
        self.set('errorMessage', JSON.stringify(reason));
      };

      var authenticate = Ember.$.post('https://example.com/users/sign_in.json', data);

      authenticate.then(done, fail);
    }
  }
});
```

What am I missing here? I'm pretty new to Ember so it might be something simple. Also, if it's relevant, I've used the Yeoman Ember package to build the app, so it's version 1.0.0, not the 1.3.0 current stable.

```
"DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0"
"DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0"
"DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 2.0.3"
```

EDIT:

So, if I change the `authenticate` promise line to:

```
authenticate.then(done);
```

Nothing happens, while

```
authenticate.then(done).then(undefined, fail);
```

causes `fail` to fire; I know they're analogous to the original, but it's suggesting that `undefined` is what the promise is being returned. I'm going to re-check the server payload now.

EDIT 2:

I suspect that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718156/jquery-ajax-post-request-to-a-ruby-on-rails-server-gives-a-json-parse-error-on) is describing a similar problem. The controller hook that returns the JSON data is as follows:

```
@key = {key: user.key}
logger.debug @key.to_json
render :json => @key
```

EDIT 3:

The FireFox network inspector in the response panel says `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turns out the problem was to do with CORS. Using [this gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors), and the code below, we were able to successfully retrieve the response body. It was being blocked at the browser level, perhaps accounting for the JSON.parse error as there was an empty response body.

In `application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```